# Clatrix Multiplication Matrix

Tags: matrix, clojure, multiplication

I have 2 matrix, matrix A = [[1 2 3][4 5 6]] and matrix B = [[10 20][20 30][30 40]], 2 x 3 and 3 x 2 matrix.

The problem is, when i use core.matrix.operator to Multiply those matrix, i got these result :

(M/* A B)

[[10  60  120]
  [120 100 240]]

which the true result is 
[[140 200]
[320 470]]

and when using "mmul", the clatrix matrix resulting an error. do anyone know how to perform multiplication using clatrix matrix?

PS : i've got this error

java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Var$Unbound cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

Comment: It would be helpful to know *what* the error is.

Comment: If this is still broken for you, could you please include the code where you call mmul and the error that results.

Comment: ( @ArthurUlfeldt and NathanDavis ) added the error on post, i already resolve it by using quantisan/clatrix instead mikera/clatrix. But, how about the error ? was it my fault ?

Comment: Solved, my ubuntu should be equipped with fortran3 lib, i don't know, but it works when install those lib and restart the machine :D